# Difference between gevent.sleep() and time.sleep() in Python

Tags: python, time, gevent

What is the difference between `gevent.sleep()` and `time.sleep()` in `Python`? When to `gevent.sleep()` and `time.sleep()`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584196/can-we-use-gevent-sleep-for-precise-timings

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111239/why-gevent-timeout-cant-raise-exception

Comment: @rene does it mean during pause in `gevent.sleep()`, corresponding thread's(paused thread) resources can be taken over by another thread? Whereas `time.sleep()` call holds onto resources?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(Recall that gevent runs multiple greenlets on a single Python thread, multiplexing them cooperatively to perform cooperative multitasking, switching amongst them as they would block for IO.)

`gevent.sleep()` will yield the current greenlet to the gevent hub, allowing other greenlets to run. `time.sleep()` will not yield to the hub; it will simply suspend the entire current thread and *all* greenlets that might like to run on it.

On the other hand, `time.sleep` will release the Python GIL and allow other Python threads the opportunity to run (but still blocking all greenlets on the calling thread), whereas `gevent.sleep` does not release the GIL (unless there are no other greenlets ready to run on the calling thread).

If you have monkey-patched your program (early enough) using `gevent.monkey.patch_all()`, then `time.sleep` simply becomes an alias for `gevent.sleep` and there is no difference.

In a program using gevent, monkey patching or explicitly using `gevent.sleep` is generally recommended instead of `time.sleep`, otherwise you won't achieve the full benefits of cooperative greenlets.

More details are provided in [the introductory gevent documentation](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#event-loop), specifically the sections on the event loop, cooperative multitasking, and pseudothreads (greenlets).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on `whereas gevent.sleep does not release the GIL (unless there are no other greenlets ready to run on the calling thread)`? My little test seems to testify that `gevent.sleep` does release the GIL: https://gist.github.com/vzts/a647b41d8a2e25d834c7309729a47624